# Cannot load Excel Worksheet Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

The following lines of code cause the error message

> The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.

when executed in Visual Studio 2019. However, if executed in Visual Studio 2017, the code runs fine. The Target framework is .Net Framework 4.5.1.

```
excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

excelDatei = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(file);

//This line causes the error
excelBlattSchaechte = excelDatei.Sheets["sheetname"];
```

Comment: Which dot net framework you are using in this project?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new project as .NET Framework.

Comment: Please add this as a comment, not as an answer. There is a difference in comment and answer.